# Apply Linux command recursively to all files in directory of single (.sh) type

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal, directory

I am trying to apply this command `sed -i -e 's/\r$//'` to all Shell (`.sh`) files in my directory I have tried:

```
sed -i -e -R 's/\r$//' *.sh
```

But this throws an unknown character error.

Any help would be great cheers!

Comment: I don't see reference to a `-R` argument in any of the man pages I've been able to find. What flag is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an argument order issue. `-e` expects the expression/script as the next argument and you are giving it `-R`.

Swap those two arguments `sed -i -e '....'`.

That being said the `dos2unix` program exists for this purpose as well.

Comment: @OtisWright That flag is from your post. You'll also notice I posted a comment asking about it since I couldn't find it anywhere.